# How to install android application in android without using adb?

Tags: android, apk, adb, android-install-apk

i have just  `android terminal`

- i dont have `adb` to `install apk`.
- i dont have double click on apk
  and install that application.

so is there any command available using that i can install application on android shell?

Comment: If you want to instll it thriugh command then down adb drivers fro your mobile then enable USB debugging and fire adb install app_name.apk command.

Comment: Using code in your application???

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, try this:

```
pm install apk.apk
```