# How to install apk files from PC?

Tags: android, adb

I want to install apk file from PC to tablet.
But the problem is that adb is disabled in tablet.

So is there any way I can install apk files from  PC to tablet without using adb?

Comment: you can copy and past in Your Tablet any Drive or Folder and just tap on apk file it ask for installation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12035582/840861

Comment: there are 8 apk files that i want to install.
So i cant click on each and every apk file.
As it is time consuming.
So i want a way by which i can install all 8 files from pc to tablet

Comment: dear i have no idea about install 8 apk automatically  @NinadChilap

Comment: hmmm... download pc suite and intall it from PC but this take much time than copying files to sdcard and run..freak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can save apk file into your device's sdcard. For that do the following.
In ddms, select on sdcard. click on "push files to device", and give the apk file path in your pc. Now your apk is inside your sdcard. and from there you can install.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the apk to the sdcard and install it on the tablet. (apk is available in the bin folder of you eclipse project after you have built the project)